# Is there a Stack Exchange site to discuss product suggestions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need a product recommendation. I have a scenario where I want to scare off wild animals with a kind of sound box and I want to ask people if they know products which could help me to do that.

Any idea which site I could use for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is Software Recommendations and Hardware Recommendations (as in [*electronic devices*, not your car, etc.](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/266/411)), but there is no general or outdoor recommendation site.

Not sure, but it seems [Home Improvements](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) does allow recommendations to some extent; maybe you'll have some luck there. See or ask on their meta first if such questions are allowed.

Please do note that we are not a forum and we don't discuss things here, so if that is what you want: there is no Stack Exchange site suitable for that.

Comment: HW recs is definitely *not* restricted to computer hardware, it's just that happens to be one of the more popular topics.

Comment: @JasonC Okay, is 'electronics in general' a better description?

Comment: That's probably more along the lines of the trend there. That community was in a rather volatile stage of defining itself the last time I was there (see https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware?noredirect=1&lq=1 and http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50/140, for example), I don't know what they settled on. At the time they seemed to welcome non-computer/electronic questions as a refreshing change of pace. On the other hand regardless of their topic width most of the community is familiar with electronics so other topics might not even get answers.

Comment: Okay, for me that sounds as: ask on their meta and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

I would try Electronics as I have had the best luck with this type of device. Personally, I would use an Arduino and a couple of relays.